# Creating a set of classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a set that can be filled with instances of a class. I thought that a requirement for a set is that elements can be compared, and thus in this case I need to tell my class how they can be compared. I created the following class:

```
class Myclass
    {
    public:
    Myclass(int i):storedval(i) {}
    int getval(){return storedval;}

    friend bool operator> (Myclass &first, Myclass &second)
        {
        return first.getval()>second.getval();
        }
    friend bool operator< (Myclass &first, Myclass &second)
        {
        return first.getval()<second.getval();
        }   

    private:
    int storedval;
    };
```

But when I try to add instances to a set like this:

```
Myclass a(50);
set<Myclass> Bunchofclasses;
Bunchofclasses.insert(a);
```

It gives me a bunch of error text that I think tells me it doesn't understand the > and < operators. How should this be done properly?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the errors.

Comment: By the way, as the comparison operators uses the public `getval` function, they don't actually need to be friends with the class.

Comment: juanchopanza's post already helped me, but I pasted the errors here:http://shrib.com/VNGKgtoQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `const` references to the comparison function because it should not be allowed to modify the items being compared:

```
friend bool operator< (const Myclass& first, const Myclass& second)
{ //                   ^^^^^                 ^^^^^
  return first.getval() < second.getval();
}
```

This will require that you make `getVal()` `const` as well. This makes it callable on `const` instances or via `const` references:

```
int getval() const {return storedval;}
//           ^^^^^
```

Note that you do not need `operator>` for the set to work. Less-than is enough.

Strictly speaking, you do not need a `friend` function here, since you are calling `public` member functions. The only thing that `friend` brings here is to allow you to declare a non-member function inside of the class definition.

Comment: Is "friend bool operator< (const Myclass& first, const Myclass& second) { ... }" legit C++?

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

Elements of a set are immutable, so the set needs to be able to compare `const` values. So the comparison needs to be:

```
friend bool operator< (Myclass const &first, Myclass const &second)
//                             ^^^^^                 ^^^^^
```

(You should probably also do this with `operator>` and any other non-mutating operations you provide; but `set` only needs `operator<`).

Also, in order to access the value of a `const` object, the accessor also needs to be `const`:

```
int getval() const
//           ^^^^^
```